# Activity indicator while loading images [iphone]

Tags: iphone, image, uiactivityindicatorview

I've a big problem with the iPhone application that I'm developing.

When you run the application you see a image-stream from different users.
Actually, when you start my app or you click the refresh button you see a modal round rectangle with "Refreshing..", when finish the refreshing, you can see all images. But this takes too times, specially for slow connections.

Now checkout this screenshot from different apps:

[image] [image]

[image]

The applications are Nuji, Picplz and Instagram.
When you run these application you see instantaneously the stream and when you scroll down and the other images get focus, the image start loading and you see an Activity Indicator.

I want something like this, I want an activity indicator while images loading and maybe, for increase application speed, start loading images on focus and stop loading the others.

I hope I explain myself well.
Please if you can help me.

Thank you very much and sorry for my english.

Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into the Three20 framework on Github https://github.com/facebook/three20.  Using that framework you can get that capability for free, using TTImageView.

Updated:  Also I thought of another place I've seen this capability.  The developers at enormego offer a solution too.  http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. There's a tutorial/example for use it? On their site there's nothing.

Comment: Three20.info has some limited documentation.  http://three20.info/article/2010-10-07-Three20-Tidbits